# When I use the sign function of @types/jsonwebtoken I get an error

Tags: node.js, jwt

When I use function sign:

```
const token = await sign(
    { userId: user.user_id },
    config.jwtSecret,
    { expiresIn: '2d' }
)
```

Because `config.jwtSecret` is type of string, so the error is:

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.ts(2345)

The reason for this error is because of the code：

```
export function sign(
    payload: string | Buffer | object,
    secretOrPrivateKey: Secret,
    options?: SignOptions,
): string;
export function sign(
    payload: string | Buffer | object,
    secretOrPrivateKey: null,
    options?: SignOptions & { algorithm: "none" },
): string;
```

How should I fix this error?

I try set the type of config.jwtSecret is any，but it must add `{ algorithm: "none" }`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming config.jwtSecret is of type string | null
const token = await sign(
  { userId: user.user_id },
  config.jwtSecret as Secret | null,
  { expiresIn: '2d' }
);
```

use this format

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This does not work, the error will be:
Argument 'null' of type 'Secret | is not assignable to argument of type 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the type of config.jwtSecret is null during runtime or can possibly be null. The sign method requires a secret (cannot be null) so ensure your config.jwtSecret is actually not null

```
// try console.log(config.jwtSecret) to verify
const token = await sign(
    { userId: user.user_id },
    config.jwtSecret as string,
    { expiresIn: '2d' }
)
```